# Get bottom and right position of an element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the position of an element within the window like so:

```
var link = $(element);

var offset = link.offset();
var top = offset.top;
var left = offset.left;
var bottom = $(window).height() - link.height();
bottom = offset.top - bottom;
var right = $(window).width() - link.width();
right = offset.left - right;
```

However the bottom and right have `-` in front of them... Why is this? as the numbers are correct just they should NOT be minus.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Instead of

```
var bottom = $(window).height() - link.height();
bottom = offset.top - bottom;
```

Why aren't you doing

```
var bottom = $(window).height() - top - link.height();
```

Edit: Your mistake is that you're doing

```
bottom = offset.top - bottom;
```

instead of

```
bottom = bottom - offset.top; // or bottom -= offset.top;
```

Answer (score 37):

```
var link = $(element);
var offset = link.offset();

var top = offset.top;
var left = offset.left;

var bottom = top + link.outerHeight();
var right = left + link.outerWidth();
```

Answer (score 12):

```
// Returns bottom offset value + or - from viewport top
function offsetBottom(el, i) { i = i || 0; return $(el)[i].getBoundingClientRect().bottom }

// Returns right offset value
function offsetRight(el, i) { i = i || 0; return $(el)[i].getBoundingClientRect().right }

var bottom = offsetBottom('#logo');
var right = offsetRight('#logo');
```

This will find the distance from the top and left of your viewport to your element's exact edge and nothing beyond that.  So say your logo was 350px and it had a left margin of 50px, variable 'right' will hold a value of 400 because that's the actual distance in pixels it took to get to the edge of your element, no matter if you have more padding or margin to the right of it.

If your box-sizing CSS property is set to border-box it will continue to work just as if it were set as the default content-box.

Comment: Best answer for me!

Answer (score 7):

Vanilla Javascript Answer

```
var c = document.getElementById("myElement").getBoundingClientRect();
var bot = c.bottom;
var rgt = c.right;
```

To be clear the element can be anything so long as you have allocated an id to it `<img>` `<div>` `<p>` etc.

for example

```html
<img
    id='myElement'
    src='/img/logout.png'
    className='logoutImg img-button'
    alt='Logout'
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) for this

```
var link = $(element);
var position = link.position(); //cache the position
var right = $(window).width() - position.left - link.width();
var bottom = $(window).height() - position.top - link.height();
```

Comment: In jQuery doc there is no reference to "right" attribute in result object for position(). [Doc here](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: Yep, but it should be offset instead of position, offset is top/left depending on document, position refers to parent.

Comment: @Mordhak, Yes, but as you can see I am using `windows.width()` and similar for further calculations as well.

Comment: be careful with position. It dosn't count margin if present

Answer (score 3):

Here is a jquery function that returns an object of any class or id on the page

```
var elementPosition = function(idClass) {
            var element = $(idClass);
            var offset = element.offset();

            return {
                'top': offset.top,
                'right': offset.left + element.outerWidth(),
                'bottom': offset.top + element.outerHeight(),
                'left': offset.left,
            };
        };


        console.log(elementPosition('#my-class-or-id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Testing</div>
<div id="result" style="margin:1em 4em; background:rgb(200,200,255); height:500px"></div>
<div style="background:rgb(200,255,200); height:3000px; width:5000px;"></div>

<script>
(function(){
    var link=$("#result");

    var top = link.offset().top; // position from $(document).offset().top
    var bottom = top + link.height(); // position from $(document).offset().top

    var left = link.offset().left; // position from $(document).offset().left
    var right = left + link.width(); // position from $(document).offset().left

    var bottomFromBottom = $(document).height() - bottom;
    // distance from document's bottom
    var rightFromRight = $(document).width() - right;
    // distance from document's right

    var str="";
    str+="top: "+top+"<br>";
    str+="bottom: "+bottom+"<br>";
    str+="left: "+left+"<br>";
    str+="right: "+right+"<br>";
    str+="bottomFromBottom: "+bottomFromBottom+"<br>";
    str+="rightFromRight: "+rightFromRight+"<br>";
    link.html(str);
})();
</script>
```

The result are

```
top: 44
bottom: 544
left: 72
right: 1277
bottomFromBottom: 3068
rightFromRight: 3731
```

in chrome browser of mine.

When the document is scrollable, `$(window).height()` returns height of browser viewport, not the width of document of which some parts are hiden in scroll. See http://api.jquery.com/height/ .