# Unable to get the position of Div after animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to animate a `div` on a link `click` to *3px* at `bottom` if the position is already *30%*, and goes up if it's *3px*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#picsClick').click(function () {

        if ($('#mainLogo').position().bottom === '30%') {
            $("#mainMenu").animate({ bottom: "3px" }, 1100);
        }
        else if (($('#mainLogo').position().bottom === '3px')) {
            $("#mainMenu").animate({ bottom: "30%" }, 1100);

        }

    });
});
```

Somehow it does not run as I have set mainMenu `div` position to `bottom` *30%* and it's position is `absolute`.
Thanks.

Comment: Add this as your first line in your click handler: `alert($('#mainLogo').position().bottom);`

Comment: Did that, it says Undefined.

Comment: CAn you make an fiddle, that would help out alot.

Comment: sorry pal, i am quite new here, i dont know how to make fidde.

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by position() only contains the properties left and top. So bottom is and unexisting property and therefor your code fails.

For more information take a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Answer (score 0):

The jquery position API does gives an element's coordinates. X and Y - which for you would mean top and left. You would need to refactor your logic around these. Even after you do that, you should note that the returned values are numbers - absolute values based on your elements position w.r.t page's dimensions. You cannot expect percentages. Hence your comparison logic too would change.

For example, if this were your element:

```
<input type="text" id="inpId" name="address" value="* Property Address :" style="top: 30%; position: absolute; ">
console.log(typeof $('#inpId').position()['top'])  // "number"
console.log(typeof $('#inpId').position()['bottom'])  // "undefined"
```

See [jquery position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

EDIT: to center your logic around bottom, you need to calculate the same in terms of top. See this question:

[Get bottom and right position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872128/get-bottom-and-right-position-of-an-element)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So how can i really animate the dv to bottom 0px and then on another click animate to t0p?