# Scroll animation scrolls down only at some point

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

What I want is, the scroll should go at the bottom of the div. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get bottom and right position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872128/get-bottom-and-right-position-of-an-element)

Comment: Add the #content.height() to #content.offset().top like #content.offset().top+#content.height()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"What I want is, the scroll should go at the bottom of the div"*

Now you scroll to the top of the div, because `offset().top` calculates, where this div starts. If you want to scroll to the bottom of the div, you can simply add the height of the div too, like this:

```
scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top + $('#content').height()
```

Comment: It now goes almost at the bottom but not exactly at the bottom

Comment: @zahidhasanemon is there enough space below this div, where we can scroll? If not, sure, you can't scroll down more than it's possible

Comment: Got this. Thanks :)